# What the md5_10m and how to calculate md5_10m using python?

Tags: javascript, python, file-upload, reverse-engineering, md5sum

i use this code to calculate md5 for file to use it in request to upload file

params name vgroup

but javascript generating different md5 than python when file > 10MB

my code:

```
import hashlib , os

def file_hash(file_path : str):

    '''
    retrun hash_filesize

    example:
        `835e7e4510fb9614d6d2d43ba1de1dc7_2544962`
       
    '''

    st = os.stat(file_path)
    file_size  = st.st_size

    
    md5Hash = hashlib.md5(open(file_path , 'rb' ).read()) .hexdigest()
    return f'{md5Hash}_{file_size}'
```

javascript code:

[image: part from javascriot code]

full js code here:

https://www.moneycase.io/public/js/chunk/pc/campaigns/file-manager.8908aa3a.js

Comment: Uh, the code you're pointing to is unformatted and nearly impossible to read.  But meanwhile.  The Python code is literally calculating the md5 of the file from its contents.  The JS code seems to believe its and already calculated attribute, and I've no idea where that attribute comes from.   MD5 is MD5.  Both JS and Python will return the same result if it's done properly.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes but in js give me different result when file bigger than 10 mb

I use developtools in browser to format js code

Comment: Have you tried `openssl md5 <filename>` at the shell to find out what the actual md5 should be?  That'll tell you whether JS or Python is wrong.